# Estimate Borel Sets with Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We're given the measure space $(X,\mathscr{A}, \mu)$with $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$with $X_i\subset X_{i+1}\subset ...$, $X_i$are open for all *i* and $\mu(X_i)<+\infty\space\space\space\space \forall i$. Then we want to show that for every Borel set *B* there exists an open set *U* where $\mu(B-U)<\epsilon$.

Here's my argument:

Pick closed sets $c_i\subset X_i-B$ with $\mu((X_i-c_i)-B)=\mu((X_i-B)-c_i)<\frac\epsilon{2^i}$. Let $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (X_i-c_i).$ Then recognizing that $X_i-c_i=X_i\bigcap c_i^c$ is the intersection of open sets reveals that G must be open. Moreover, $B\subset G$ is clear and thus we can consider $G-B$. If follows that $\mu(G-B)<\epsilon$.

My problem is explaining why I can pick these closed sets. Once I can do that I have the problem completed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Since $B$ is Borel,it's measurable. Likewise, since $X_i$ is open (? you didn't state this at the beginning of the question, but at the end, so I'm assuming that $X_i$ is open), it's measurable. Therefore, $X_i-B$ is measurable. Therefore, you can approximate it with closed elementary rectangles (or some other shape), and choose this rectangle to be $c_i$.

Comment: You need to clarify how the topology relates to the measure for the question to be meaningful.

Comment: Yes, the $X_i$ are suppose to be open. So all I would need to state is that since the sets are measurable I can then approximate them with closed sets? Is there a proof of that statement somewhere that I can look at?